# Java Spring Application Deadlock

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, deadlock, executorservice

I have some general questions about the concept of deadlocks.
I am trying to learn the basics how to learn the basics of building multi threaded applications and I just need some key words and basically point me in the right direction what to look into, since I have problems understanding some basic concepts.

I want to learn how can I programm queues in java so I can hold elements prior to processing. For example, if my application have many notifications, I want them to put them in a queue and process them asynchronously, so they don't access the database simultaneously and avoid DEADLOCKS.

Therefore, I started studying the java.util.concurrent package in Java, but before that I just have some basic questions.

Is the java.util.Queue interface the right approach to this problem?

I have another basic question to a behaviour which I dont understand. Let's assume we have a basic application where multiple users can log in and edit their profile information (Firstname, Birthdate...). If two users are logged in and edit their information simultaneously, then both information need to be peristed in the same user table. Could this lead to a deadlock, since both access the same table? How does Spring handle this?

EDIT:

As I described above, I have an application that handled multiple tasks which produces sometimes deadlocks. I want them to put in a queue and then process each task asynchronously.

I have done some research and I think that the best solution would be to use the Producer-consumer pattern with the ExecutorService with a BlockingQueue like described in this article: https://allegro.tech/2015/05/thread-pools.html

What do you think? I just want some ideas if this solution is good enough for my problem description? Are there better ways to do it?

Comment: "*Could this lead to a deadlock, since both access the same table? How does Spring handle this?*" - In this case, it is not Spring's responsibility to ensure deadlock-freeness, but the one of the database. As long as only one table is involved, there should be no deadlock.

Comment: Processing notifications out of a queue isn't a magic cure for all deadlocks.  It just means that the processing of one notification won't ever deadlock with the _processing of another notification_.